# Treating debt of financial firm as Source of Capital, why small change in value of firm's asset value causes large change in Equity Value?

Tags: banking, stock-valuation

Let us treat debt as source of capital for Financial Service Firm and firm is operating on High Financial Leverage. Then how small changes in the value of the firm’s assets can translate into big swings in equity value?

Here is Original Paragraph from paper titled **Valuing Financial Service Firms** by **Aswath Damodaran**

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework?

Comment: @Fattie Its not Homework..
I was just reading this Paper to understand these things out of curiosity.. BTW I am a Physics student.. Don't judge too quickly..

Comment: Welcome new user!  @CrownedEagle  honestly no offense .. "homework" on here is just shorthand for "a canned question taken from a textbook or such"; for whatever reason they're supposed to be closed.  one close vote means nothing, so, all good!

Comment: @Fattie So what one should do if someone is reading out of curiosity and got stuck on couple of lines as I lack b/g in this subject. So if you know some other place, forum etc do point me to..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an example of the concept of leverage. Suppose a $1M company is financed with $900K of debt (90%) and $100K of equity (10%). Then say the company's net assets increases by 5% (5% of $1M is $50K) due to normal operations (net profit). Since debt is unchanged at this point, that means that the company's equity (assets - liabilities) goes from $100K to  $150K, or a *** 50% increase ***. Because the firm is financed 90% with debt, it has a leverage of 10X, meaning that for every 1$ change in assets, equity changes by 10%, so a 5% change in assets results in a 50% change in equity.

But leverage works both ways - a *loss* would result in a drastic drop in equity. If the company *lost* 10%, reducing assets by $100M, all of its equity would be wiped out due to the leverage.

Comment: Just Small query.. A. Damodaran wrote this while explaining difference between Fin. Serv. Firms and non-Financial one. So the point author want to make is.. **Since banks operate at high leverage they can be wiped out by small change in asset value whereas other firms not, Right?**

Comment: That sounds a bit dramatic as banks have the ability to borrow money very cheaply from the fed, but conceptually that makes sense (I am not an expert in that realm though)

Comment: Okay.. Got it..

Comment: @CrownedEagle that might have been accurate 100 years ago before the 1930s banking reforms.

Comment: @TripeHound Good catch - fixed the scales